# Swift 5, Idea for a function that would save the highest value

Tags: swift, function, max

Hello fellow programmers.

Im building my little swift game and I stumbled upon a problem.
I want my program to save the value of the highest Y coordinate that my ball ever acquired. So if a player went up and then down in 3d space, the Y value of the peak would be saved.
And my question isn't about implementation but an idea of a function that could solve my problem.
Keep in mind that coordinates update like 60 times per second and they aren't stored in any array or anything.

@edit
And to add to it, its not as simple as caching the change of a vector, like when the velocity is 0 because the ball is moving diagonally.. so even when it starts falling the velocity still isnt 0 it just slows down..

```
let ball = ballNode.presentation
        let ballPosition = ball.position
        
        let targetPosition = SCNVector3(x: ballPosition.x, y: ballPosition.y, z:ballPosition)  //ball spawn point
```

Comment: Look at [max(_:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538951-max)

Comment: Okay but it would need 2 values to compare. First, the actual height of the ball and second ? What would be the second one?  I would have to store previous Y values somehow? How?

Comment: To *save the value of the highest Y coordinate*  you have to compare two values. Declare a property and assign the return value of the `max` function with the parameters the property itself and the current y coordinate

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you guys, Vadian and Leo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a maxY property initialize it with zero.

```
var maxY: CGFloat = .zero
```

As suggested in comment by vadian compare the last value with the current one. You can also extend Comparable protocol and implement a mutating method:

```
extension Comparable {
    mutating func max(_ y: Self) {
        self = Swift.max(self, y)
    }
}
```

---

```
maxY.max(ballPosition.y)
```